# Word 365 Allow Macros to run on Read-Only/Protected View

Tags: microsoft-word, vba, macros, microsoft-word-365

I am attempting to upgrade our company to Microsoft 365 x86 from Office 2019x86. We are currently stuck on 32bit because our electronically controlled document process currently has VBA macros that use 32bit DLLs. These DLLs are used in VBA macros to pull new data into DOC files and make sure everything is accurate in them every time they are opened.

All of this was working fine on Office 2019. When these documents are downloaded, they are opened and marked as protected due to being marked read-only on the file properties. With Office 2019, this does not stop the macro from running. With M365, these documents fail to run the macro as they are marked as Viewing only. I have attempted to push out GPO that forces trusted locations and trust the macros running but they still fail. The error I get from the VBA macro is below.

`Run-time error '6124': You are not allowed to edit this selection because it is protected.`

I have been able to get a workaround for this by deleting the all the registry entries within `'HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Office'`, then rebooting. The behavior that is expected works temporarily with this method but then the issue comes back after a random amount of time.

Another workaround is going to the file properties and unchecking read-only. This is not an option for our end users but works for admins when testing.

What are some more potential solutions to try resolving this or the exact registry key/value that is causing this behavior?

Answer (score 0):

Something to test, as a workaround: [Change ownership in the Registry key](https://www.askvg.com/guide-how-to-restore-trustedinstaller-as-default-owner-of-a-file-or-folder-in-windows/) `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Office` to TrustedInstaller and delete permission to change/write to it to make it unlikely MS Office will mess with it. **N.B.** Before making the change, export the key to a .reg file to make it easier to revert. Afterwards, test if another export to .reg can change ownership on another PC.

Ownership change has some obvious disadvantages, though.

- It will make future updates of *Office* more difficult.
- *Office* will not be able to save any *other* changes to that key. Try to narrow down the specific *subkey* that needs to be protected, and change ownership to that alone.
- Deploying this to many machines may be difficult, if it cannot be done with a .reg file.
- There may be security issues, keeping the old 32-bit DLL's.

Of course, a better solution would be to contact the vendor of the original document compliance pplication and get a version compatible with newer releases of MS *Office*.

[BTW, have you tested an alternative to *Office*, such as [LibreOffice](https://www.libreoffice.org/), for compatibility with the existing macros? Since it might not be practical to change application suites in a corporate environment, this would be to satisfy curiosity, and possibly to give the software vendor motivation to update the DLL's.]

Comment: Hi there, so I've been doing a lot of testing and have narrowed it down to the registry values in `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Office\16.0\Common\ExperimentConfigs`.
Deleting all the subkeys in that folder and changing the permissions to read-only for user works. The problem I am running into now is how to deploy this out to the whole company via GPO or an SCCM Powershell script. I will update once I figure it out